# How to fill a DevExpress GridControl with string and date fields?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, datetime, devexpress-wpf

Should I put in a project with VS2010 and DevExpress in C # interface that covers a UserControl, which has a GridControl and its objective is to fill the grid of all the operations performed by the user log.

I made a list

```
ObservableCollection <LogStruct> loglist <LogStruct> = new ObservableCollection ();
        public ObservableCollection <LogStruct> loglist
        {
            get {return loglist; }
        }
```

and a data structure

```
public class LogStruct
    {
        public string Message {get; the set; }
        public DateTime Date {get; the set; }

        public LogStruct (string mess, DateTime date)
        {
            Message = mess;
            Date = date;
        }
```

I also wrote the property in xaml

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="grid_logoperations" AutoGenerateColumns="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataLog}">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView x:Name="tableview" AutoWidth="True" NewItemRowPosition="Bottom"/>
        </ Dxg: GridControl.View>
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>

            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="LogMessage" x:Name="columnmess" ReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" UnboundType="String"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="LogDate" x:Name="columndata" ReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" UnboundType="DateTime"/>
            
          
            
        </ Dxg: GridControl.Columns>

    </ Dxg: GridControl>
```

My question is: how do I write on the GridControl and to appear in video messages Log?
Thanks to those who help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify names of the corresponding properties as the GridColumn.FieldName property value (in your case "Message" and "Date", **not** "LogMessage" and "LogDate"). You should not also assign the UnboundType property when columns are bounded to the real data source.